# Android Spinner not clearly visible in ICS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, spinner

I was working with `Spinner` in `Android 2.3 Ginger Bread` version which working fine. But when i run the app in `Android ICS 4.0` visibility of text in  `Spinner` is poor. It is not clearly visible.

Can any one help? when i tried to change the background but the arrow of `Spinner` is gone. Is there any other way?

Comment: Please post your spinner code in particular the themee/styling. A sceenshot would also be helpful.

Comment: thnkz ..i didnt used any theme for that..but now see 1 post in net that because of default theme of ics its like that..is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You target version may be in `Android 4.0 ICS` and compiling with `Android 4.0 ICS`. So its show like that. You want to show `Spinner` as same as `Android 2.3` set

`android:targetSdkVersion="10"` in android manifeast file and also change the compile version in project.properties to `target=android-10`

Comment: thnkz..i created a custom layout for spinner and set text color as black.so that it can be seen

Comment: But if i change to android:targetSdkVersion="10" then i guess it wont run in higher versions?Iam sry if am wrng .iam new to android field.

Comment: @Sjk No. It will run. Keep it mind that, all lower versions are runs in higher versions but not all higher version are runs in lower versions.

Comment: If changed like that then is it possible to use the features which is available in 4.0 ?

Comment: @Sjk If u changed the target version to "10". You can't use the Higher versions API. That's not problem actually, because its only few api's. Other then that you want do the 2.3 spinner in 4.0, you have to set the custom background for the spinner. Check this http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-custom-spinner-with-custom.html